# How to Implement or Handle the CountDownTimer using Kotlin Coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, countdowntimer, android-handler

I build an android app **Countdown Timer** using Kotlin. When I start the timer using **Coroutines** it throws an error as follows.

Need your help that:

- How I can handle or implement the Countdown Timer's handler which will run on a different
  thread instead of the main thread ... **OR** ... How to implement the timer using kotlin coroutines?

**Error Text:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-1,5,main] that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

**Code:**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        btnStartPause.setOnClickListener {
            if (isRunning) {
                pauseTimer()
            } else {
                val time = edtTxtTimer.text.toString().trim()
                timeInMilliSeconds = time.toLong() * 60000L // 1m = 60,000ms
               
                CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
                        startTimer(timeInMilliSeconds)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    private fun startTimer(time_in_milli_second: Long) {
        countdown_timer = object : CountDownTimer(time_in_milli_second, 1000) {
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                timeInMilliSeconds = millisUntilFinished
                updateUI()
            }

            override fun onFinish() {
                btnStartPause.text = "Start"
                loadConfeti()
            }
        }
        countdown_timer.start()

        isRunning = true
        btnStartPause.text = "Pause"
        btnReset.visibility = View.GONE
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to implement **CountDownTimer** to resolve the above error:

**First Way**

- Implement the timer by creating your own `Dispatcher` using the `HandlerThread`
- But this isn't the best approach

**Second Way**

- Implement the timer using `Kotlin Flows`
- Start Timer on any *Dispatcher* other than *Main Thread*
- Collect data from the Producer on `Main Thread`

Answer (score 3):

CountdownTimer can only be started from a Looper thread. This is typically only the Main thread, unless you've created your own Looper on a specific other thread. `Dispatchers.Main` is the only Kotlin-provided dispatcher that has a Looper.

You don't need to use a coroutine to start a CountdownTimer. The class automatically works in the background without blocking. That's actually the reason it needs a Looper thread...so it can trigger its `onTick` and `onFinish` on the same thread that started it without blocking that thread.